Is there metastability concern in the design of "slicer" part of serdes receiver circuit?
It seems that metastability is an important aspect of concerns when designing sequential circuits. This related to the fact that the signal must wade through the "forbidden zone" when it alters between digital 0 and 1.
In the context of serdes, on the receiver side, after equalisation, the signal usually goes through a component called "slicer", which outputs digital 0 or 1 to the later stages. It seems that the slicer makes its decision by comparing the signal with a threshold.
My question is, for the slicer for handling its input, is there still concepts of forbidden zone (or noise margin)? or, put it in another way, does the slicer has a concern of metastability for handling its input?
Note that I am focusing on the input of slicer, not the output (I believe that the output of the slicer, being digital, has the usual metastability concerns when connected to the later stages).

Is their a specific SERDES, e.g. hard IP inside a FPGA, you are interested in using, or is this a general question? If a specific SERDES can you edit a question to include a link to the SERDES datasheet.

It's more of a generic question, not related to a specific FPGA device (although at the same time I am reading AM002 from xilinx for versal GTY architecture manual, which seems do not contain too much details of how its receiver is implemented). Basically my question is more or less something like: while within a die, STA makes sure that metastability is not likely to happen; what about die 2 die communications (Serdes is one of such scenario; the other is source-sync clocking scheme such as in depicted UCIe -- I am just starting learning this subject).

As I gather from your question, you are in the course of studying the high-speed transceiver architecture and design implementation. You seem to know that the slicer is a limiter used in the decision-feedback equalizer (DFE) circuitry. If not, you can learn it from Razavi's article The Decision-Feedback Equalizer and recognize that DFE is invented to fight intersymbol interference (ISI) errors. When reading the article, pay attention how Razavi intoduces a clocked comparator component into the control-feedback loop, connecting the delay stage and the slicer into one component, a flipflop FF [page 14 (2/5), Figure 4(c)]. For convenience of readers of this post, I'm citing Razavi's explanation:

This issue [the amplitude noise amplification in the feedback loop] can be remedied if the delay element is followed by a limiter, also known as a “slicer,” so as to remove the amplitude noise [Figure  4(b)]. The loop thus stops the noise from circulating and acts as a nonlinear equalizer. For robust operation, we replace the delay stage and the slicer with a flipflop (FF) [Figure  4(c)], recognizing that typical FFs provide both a one-period delay and limiting action on the amplitude. We can say the loop feeds the FF’s decision back to the input, hence the term DFE.

The design with flipflops is prone to metastability and other well-known complications, as well. The article proceeds with considering DFE speed limitations (flipflop timing parameters, propagation delay, which, of course, are not metastability issues) and how other nonidealities can be alleviated.
Summing up, in DFE (part of the high-speed transceiver), the slicer component is a component of clocked comparator and its metastability issues should be considered in this context. To help you proceed with your sutudy, I recommend you the article Simulation and Analysis of Random Decision Errors in Clocked Comparators, IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON CIRCUITS AND SYSTEMS—I: REGULAR PAPERS, VOL. 56, NO. 8, AUGUST 2009. There is a copy of this article on the Texas A&M University site, https://people.engr.tamu.edu/spalermo/ecen689/simulation_analysis_clocked_comparators_kim_tcas1_2009.pdf. The authors elaborate the linear time-varying model of clock comparators which considers slicer metastability issues and give the BER formulas for 90- and 65-nm CMOS process designs. To support my claim that the article tackles the metastability issues, I'm citing two exerpts from the article:

While the signals in clocked comparator circuits generally make large-signal excursions during the operation, many of the important characteristics can be analyzed based on the small-signal response of the comparator when it is near the metastable point (i.e., when the input signal is conditioned so that the comparator cannot reach a firm decision within the cycle). It is because the metastable point is where the comparator decision output is most sensitive to noise and the comparator is most likely to generate decision errors.

and

However, in practical simulation, we found that the noise observed at the comparator output is not strictly additive, especially when the comparator is operating very close to the metastable point. It is possible that noises modulated by deterministic, large-signal effects such as kick-back noise overwhelm the additive Gaussian noise that we are trying to measure. As described later in Section IV, we found that it yields more accurate results to estimate the Gaussian noise power from a set of decision error probability measurements with nonzero input signal values’s for which the comparator is slightly apart from the metastable point and the additive Gaussian noise has the dominant effect on the error probability.


Thanks for your reply and provided links @V.V.T! Although I am not able to quickly digest the two reference docs (especially the latter one), you definitely answered my orignal question that metastability IS a concern for DFF-based slicer implementations. This leads to two follow-up questions.


In DFF-based slicer implementations, as metastability concern exists, does the slicer usually contain a cascading series of DFFs (as seen in CDC circuits) such that the possibility of meta-stable outputs from the slicer is decreased to a negligible level? or it's the responsibility of the latter stage of the slicer to handle possible meta-stable inputs? I have this question because in some DFE block diagrams (e.g., in Figure 4c of Razari's article), only one DFF is depicted, thus I am not sure if it's just for illustration purpose or it's also reflected real implementations.



Are there slicer implementations which is not DFF-based thus metastability is not relevant? e.g., I am not sure if op-amp can be used for implementing slicer (and if, what's the pros/cons).


While it is sure that clocked comparators as regular components of sequential circuits are not exempt from general metastability phenomenon, it will take time to answer your follow-ups. Meanwhile, you can answer the question @Chester Gillon asks in the question comment section and maybe receive a prompt answer.

Lacking a substantial expertise in high-speed transceiver designs, I fear to discuss general claims like does the slicer usually contain a cascading series of DFFs. Let's rather look into "DFE variants" of Razavi's article, a two-tap DFE architecture and a DFE with differential signal parts. These do contain master and slave latches, but the purpose is not to fight metastability, the circuits aim either to remove higher-order postcursors (Fig 5) or to illustrate the speed limitations resulting from FF timing constants (Fig 6). Why DFF cascading is not used here to fight metastability?

Because 1) there is only one clock (so the clock domain crossing events never happen) and 2) the slicer output is not forked except when used in the fb loop. The DFE here is a sort of Schmitt trigger, and, while the Schmitt trigger is also prone to metastability issues, in this particular implementation the inherent DFF delay is sufficient to unambiguously detect zero/one logic levels of the incoming signal -- provided, the DFF setup/hold times are respected.

As there may exist the designs different than that discussed in Razavi's article, I provided you with the paper on the analysis of random decision errors in clocked comparators that considers the metastability phenomenon.

I believe this consideration also partially answers your second follow-up, although I do not understand how your breaking of a clocked comparator again into a series connection of a delay line and an opamp based comparator (what we had from the beginning) can help you get rid of metastability.

Thanks for your endeavor in helping me on this question @V.V.T! It also helps me to rethink and clarify my original question.

In the first place, the context I was/am focusing on is a communication model composed by the following components (i.e., transmitter/channel/receiver, and optionally the 4th component, distributed clock. if the distributed clock is not included, it implies an embedded clock in the signal). In the context, I preassume that the input signal to the receiver is treated as analog signal, and one of the responsibilities of the receiver is to convert the analog signal to digital signal (into the local clock domain on the receiver sider).

With these assumptions, it seems that my original question boils down to the metastability of the ADC converter used in the receiver. According to this, "ADC metastability happens when a small input makes a comparator’s regeneration time longer than the time assigned by design.", and it seems (or, I believe) that metastability will be always a concern in any form of ADC, and one cannot completely avoid it (albeit clever

albeit clever schemes are possible to minimize metastability hazard, gray code in async fifo as an example). I think this sets up the background, with which my original question is more or less relating to "usually how ADC handles metastability" in the context mentioned above, particularly during link training phase when the receiver dynamically adjusts it sampling time/phase to achieve bit lock (or channel-bonding/deskew). I guess now I have a clearer goal thus I will dig a bit more on this on my own firstly. Thanks again.

Btw, in the data communication context, the consequence of metastability is most likely the increase of BER, as the output is purely data. In this sense, it seems that it's not as catastrophic as it happening in the context of sequence logic where metastabilty may lead to corrupted state machine thus malfunction of the circuit.
